# Can a woman time intercourse to avoid conception?

Tags: halacha, marriage, sexuality, pru-urvu

Can a woman whose husband already has children refuse sex with him on days she may be fertile with the goal of not conceiving?

Comment: This question is asking from some the theoretical technical legal perspective, I assume, but any couple who'd actually get to this point needs to sit down with a therapist/rabbi/etc. and make some decision they can both get on board with.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand, but looking at the way you recommended the wording. It does not matter whether she has children of her own or not, but that he already has children? Does it matter from the perspective of halacha who has the physical children?

Comment: A man is obligated in procreation and a woman is not. Accordingly, her having children already or not doesn't change anything from her perspective. (Obviously the most common case is the children are both of theirs.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, True, like in being shommer negia, applying to only the men, and women sin by touching because they made the man sin of touching not that she touched him, so in this case it would be same, preventing him from procreating is a sin, by not letting another do a mitzvah.

Comment: @Gabriel No! That's is not true! Negia applies equally to men and women! All prohibitions apply equally to men and women (except those relating to shaving and to kohanim visiting cemeteries)

Comment: Q: What do you call a couple who use the "natural rhythm" method? A: "Mommy and Daddy."

Comment: I think the answer is obviously No. This is exactly what she obligated herself in when he married her (Teshuvas Netziv if I remember correctly).

Comment: OTOH I have heard from gedolim that in the old days this was a pretty common way for people to space out their births - obviously with the husband's buy-in as well!

Comment: @MichoelR from which gedolim, source please.

Comment: @ninamag Don't have. Nothing official.

Comment: @ninamag Just a fair warning, people will be very reluctant to answer a question like this because there is no good answer. DoubleAA's answer is the only good thing to say to someone asking this - they must consult their Rabbi. The Rabbi might recommend contraception, rather than avoiding Onah, although there might be reason to suspect there are deeper problems going on and the couple should work those out

Comment: The title and body don't match. The title sounds more like what everyone used to do before contraceptives were invented. The body sounds like getting into a morredess situation, i.e. grounds for divorce and losing her kesuba.

Comment: @user6591 title and body were practically written by Double_AA (please direct your comment to him).

Comment: @Double please see the two comments above. There seems to be a title/body mismatch presently. What do you think?

Comment: @user6591 what people used to do was have both parties time intercourse, not just the woman time it. If the question doesn't match what the OP intended they should edit further to clarify.

Comment: To me, both the title and body are the same (which Double_AA suggested and/or wrote), but please @user6591 edit it to your satisfaction.